# Yaml / Swagger lint and validator in JavaScript (npm)

Tags: npm, yaml, swagger

I'm working in a project where we're versioning a .yml file which is used to define our API. Right now we don't have a lintable standard for it since everyone is using different editors etc.

I've been looking at so many different npm packages, but none seem to be able to do what http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML does, which is to lint, validate and "prettify" your .yml file.

Does anyone know if there is a good alternative for this in the world of JavaScript? What I've found is either only a validator, or it returns 404 when npm installing... Which leads me to believe that this functionality has been included in some larger swagger/yml tool for js and I just can't find it because of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We're using [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml).

```
npm install -g js-yaml
```

Then in order to prettify your YAML, you'd pass it to `js-yaml` to convert it to JSON, then pass that JSON back to `js-yaml` to convert it back to YAML.

```
js-yaml your_file.yml | js-yaml
```